# react-modal: Don't scroll parent component when Modal is opened ios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

This problem is related to #issue 191: Don't scroll parent component when Modal is opened

This problem now happens on iOS. Because the parent behind is getting scrolled. The modal sometimes appears unresponsive. I followed the recommendation using onAfterOpen callback like this:

```
<Modal
      isOpen={open}
      onRequestClose={this.handleCloseModal}
      style={styles.modal}
      contentLabel="Example Modal"
      onAfterOpen={this.disableScroll}
>
```

in the same parent, i defined disableScroll:

```
disableScroll = () => {
   document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
}
```

I also followed the css guidelines for ios:

```
parent: {
  overflow: 'hidden',
  position: 'absolute',
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%'},
```

Too bad this stops the scrolling for parent view when modal is closed too. 
Any idea how to resolve this on ios?